# Prove that an annulus is not simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I don't have complex analysis at my beck and call, and I only have a low level of knowledge in topology, but I need to prove that this metric space (for any real $r$ and $R$ with $r < R$)$$ X = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | \ r \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq R \}$$

with the Manhattan metric $d((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = |x_1-x_2| + |y_1-y_2|$ is not simply connected.

I've already prooven that it's path connected, and now I need to show there are some points $P$ and $Q$ with two paths between them such that one cannot be continuously 'morphed' into the other.

$ \ $

What I have so far is as follows:

I take $P = (0, r)$ and $Q = (0, -r)$, with $f_0$ being a path from $P$ to $Q$ going clockwise around the circle radius $r$ and $f_1$ being much the same but going counterclockwise.

Now I assume there is a function $g : [0, 1]^2 \to X$ such that:

- $g(s, 0) = f_0 (s)$
- $g(s, 1) = f_1 (s)$
- $g(0, t) = P$
- $g(1, t) = Q$

To get the final result, I need to show that this function cannot be continuous, but for the life of me I cannot.

For some context, these are the topics which have been visited during the course, roughly in order of recentness.

- Multiple connectedness
- Simple connectedness
- Pathwise connectedness
- Interior points
- Boundary points
- Open sets
- Compactness
- Complete metric spaces
- Bounded metric spaces
- Totally bounded metric spaces
- Closed sets
- Closure of a metric space
- Limit points
- Cauchy sequences
- Convergence
- Continuity
- Metric space quivalence
- Metric equivalence

**Edit**: I might have an argument that works, though it's far from rigourous. We can shrink $R$ to be as close to $r$ as we want, so we can essentially constrain the annulus down to a circle and thus force any path from the left side of the circle to the right side to go through $P$ or $Q$.

So holding $s \in (0, 1)$ constant and varying $t$ must produce a path through $P$ or $Q$ for any $s$. If for some $s$ it passes through $P$ and for some other $s$ it passes through $Q$, then there must be $s_0$ such that $\forall \epsilon >0  \ \exists \delta \leq \epsilon$ st. $s_0$ produces a path through $P$ and $s_0 + \delta$ produces a path through $Q$.

Now we can consider the path $g(s, \frac{1}{2})$, and note that it must have a discontinuity at $s_0$.

Now consider the case where all $s$ produce paths through only one of $P$ or $Q$. WOLOG: $P$. Now, at $t = \frac{1}{2}$, $s$ arbitrarily close to $1$ are mapped away from $Q$, but $1$ is always mapped to $Q$ by definition, so $g(s, \frac{1}{2})$ has a discontinuity at $s=1$. Therefore $g(s, t)$ is not continuous.

This argument is definitely iffy to me, if no one has their own argument (using sufficiently low level concepts), then criticism on the above would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know any fixed point or surjectivity theorems for continuos maps of the closed unit ball to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which are the identity on $S^1$ when restricted to the boundary of the ball?

Comment: @Thomas Nope, not even familiar.

Comment: Well, you do need at least something to prove this, some basic complex analysis would do, but you say you don't know that. What do you have available? If this is homework you should look up the most recent topic in your lectures to give us a clue what w may use.

Comment: @Thomas I've edited in a list of topics, erring on the side of completeness. If what's there doesn't seem like enough, then perhaps Complex Analysis would be alright were it sufficiently basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Compute the path integral
$$
\int\frac{x\,\mathrm{d}y-y\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+y^2}\tag{1}
$$
along the two paths from $(\sqrt{rR},0)$ to $(-\sqrt{rR},0)$ parametrized by $(\sqrt{rR}\cos(\theta),\sqrt{rR}\sin(\theta))$ for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $\theta\in[0,-\pi]$.

Use [Green's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem) to show that, on any closed contour which is the difference of two neighboring paths inside the annulus, the integral in $(1)$ is $0$. Thus, if you can continuously deform one path to another inside the annulus, the change of the integral along the paths would be $0$.

---

A simple corollary of Green's Theorem is that if a region is simply connected, and
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}G(x,y)\tag{2}
$$
at every point in that region, then, over any closed path $\gamma$ in that region,
$$
\int_\gamma F(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}y+G(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}x=0\tag{3}
$$

Comment: I'm assuming there's a result that makes this relevant, but I'm not familiar with it, and google didn't help.

Comment: This argument does not work for general continuous paths.

Comment: @G.H.Faust: Green's Theorem says that if you can continuously deform one path into the other, the change in the integral would be $0$. However, if you compute the integral along the two paths, it is different.

Comment: @robjohn: are you assuming that all the paths given by the homotopy are smooth enough? because the integral that you give it's a line integral.

Comment: @Asupollo: Not sure what you mean. There are two paths here and the integral along each is different. If the paths could be continuously deformed into each other, the integrals would be the same.

Comment: @robjohn: I mean... by the assumption of the homotopy $f_t(s)$ what I think you try to make is defining the map $t\to \int_{f_t}\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ and to prove is continous, but the integrals $\int_{f_t}\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ for paths $f_t$ with $0<t<1$ may not exist.

Comment: @Asupollo: the OP says, "I need to show there are some points P and Q with two paths between them such that one cannot be continuously 'morphed' into the other." I provide two semicircular paths that cannot be continuously morphed into one another.

Comment: @Asupollo: if the deformation of the path is continuous, then the integral should exist.

Answer (score 3):

Assume you have a continuous $g$ as stated by you.

Show that, for each $t \in [0,1]$, there exists a continuous function $\theta_{t} : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $\theta_{t}(0)=-\pi/2$ and such that $g(s,t)=|g(s,t)|(\cos\theta_{t}(s),\sin\theta_{t}(s))$. (Connectedness of $[0,1]$ can be helpful.) Then show that $\theta_{t}$ is unique by connectedness of $[0,1]$. Use known, simple contours for $f_{0}$ and $f_{1}$ in order to arrange for $\theta_{0}(1)=\pi/2$ and $\theta_{1}(1)=-3\pi/2$. Show that, for fixed $s \in [0,1]$, $\theta_{t}(s)$ is a continuous function of $t$ (because of homotopy,) and note that $\theta_{t}(1)$ has possible values $\pi/2\pm 2n\pi$ for $n=0,1,2,3,\ldots$. Use connectedness of $[0,1]$ to reach a contradiction.

Comment: I really don't understand this as a whole (pretty sure I'm missing some results I'd need about connectedness) but it's sufficiently on the ball that parts might be helpful, or the whole thing might work if I find the results to make the logical leaps. Thanks regardless.

Comment: Which of the steps that I gave you were you unable to carry out? Were you able to get a continuous angle function $\theta_{t}(s)$ for a fixed $t$? Were you able to show that, for fixed $s$, $t\mapsto \theta_{t}(s)$ is continuous because of the joint continuity of $g$? Were you able to conclude that $\theta_{t}(1)$ assumes only discrete values? Now you have a continuous function $t\mapsto \theta_{t}(1)$ on $[0,2\pi]$ that takes only discrete values. This is impossible unless this function is constant, which cannot be because $\theta_{0}(1)$ and $\theta_{1}(1)$ are different.

Comment: To use connectedness to show the existence of $\theta_{t}(s)$ for $0 \le s \le 1$, let $S = \{ s' : \theta \mbox{exists on } [0,s'] \}$. Then $S$ isn't empty, and you can show that $S$ is open in $[0,1]$ because, if $s \in S$, then you can extend $\theta$ just beyond $s$. You can show $S$ is closed in $[0,1]$ because if $S$ is defined on $[0,s)$ for some $s > 0$, then you can show that $\lim_{t\uparrow s}\theta(t)$ exists. Because $[0,1]$ is connected, and $S$ is non-empty, relatively open and relatively closed, then $S=[0,1]$; that's how you get a function $\theta$ on the entire interval.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, but I managed to construct an argument from the other answer which was much simpler. I probably would have learned more with this, but it was much harder to dig my teeth into!

Comment: You should keep in mind that a general continuous homotopy will not necessarily give you curves over which you can integrate.

Comment: @TrialAndError: I have already proved that $\theta_t$ is continuous for every $t\in [0,1]$, but how does that help proving that $\theta_t(s)$ is continuous as a function of $t$? or what is the purpose of it?